# Error message "list index is out of range"

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
def third_largest(a):
    count = 0
    b = 0
    while count < 2 or count > 2:
        for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
            if a[b] < a[i]:
                count += 1
        b += 1
    print(a[b])
```

I want to get third largest number in a list.

Firstly I pick up first element and compare with all other elements and then pick up second element if `count` is equal to `2` then I print out my answer.

But why I am getting the error message `'list index is out of range'` in the `for` loop? I am really very confused.

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback and some example input data.

Comment: I suggest just removing the `else` part entirely or doing `pass` instead of `count+=0` as it does nothing worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `print` into the `for` loop:

```
def third_largest(a):
    count = 0
    b = 0
    while count < 2 or count > 2:
        for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
            print("b: {0}, count: {1}, i: {2}".format(b, count, i))
            if a[b] < a[i]:
                count += 1
            else:
                count += 0
        b += 1
    print(a[b])
```

we can see exactly what the problem is:

```
>>> third_largest([1, 2, 3])
b: 0, count: 0, i: 0
b: 0, count: 0, i: 1
b: 1, count: 1, i: 0
b: 1, count: 1, i: 1
b: 2, count: 1, i: 0
b: 2, count: 1, i: 1
b: 3, count: 1, i: 0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    third_largest([1, 2, 3])
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 8, in third_largest
    if a[b] < a[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

You do not have any checking to ensure that `b` is an index within the bounds of `a`.

Also, you could just use `while count != 2:` and note that `count += 0` is utterly pointless. There is a much easier way to approach this, too (***hint***: if `a` were in order, where would the third largest value be?)

Answer (score 2):

```
def third_largest(a):
    if len(a) < 3:
        raise ValueError
    # Sort array, smalles ahead, and return item on index -3
    return sorted(a)[-3]
```

Use pythons own methods, now you are sure you have the right number

Comment: While this may provide a solution to the problem OP is trying to solve, it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: The OP wants the third *largest*, either set `reverse=True` or take index `[-3]`

Comment: @Tim; True, jonrsharpe's answer explains what is wrong and even gives the hint towards my solution.
@Jon; True, my mistake, will edit the code

Answer (score 0):

Complex is better than complicated.

```
def third_largest(a):
    if len(a)>2: return list(set(sorted(a)))[-3]
    return -1
```